# SDL 8.5 Content Delivery (CIS)

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, discovery-service

We have around 26 services total running in different ports. Sometimes when we run the `java -jar discovery-registration.jar read` to make sure the discovery service has the correct capabilities and has the proper deployer/content services, we don't get the values we expect. We then run `java -jar discovery-registration.jar forceSync` and `java -jar discovery-registration.jar update`. This resolves the issue for this group of services, but then another group of services get 'bumped' and when I run `java -jar discovery-registration.jar read` their deployer and content service are now assigned to the previous group.
We have 3 groups of services (legacy, normal, and express) with 3 subgroups each (live, stage, preview), and each subgroup has 1 Discovery, 1 Content, and 1 Deployer-combined service.

```
.
├── express
│   ├── live
│   │   ├── content
│   │   ├── deployer-combined
│   │   └── discovery
│   ├── preview
│   │   ├── content
│   │   ├── deployer-combined
│   │   └── discovery
│   └── stage
│       ├── content
│       ├── deployer-combined
│       └── discovery
├── legacy
│   ├── live
│   │   ├── content
│   │   ├── deployer-combined
│   │   └── discovery
│   ├── preview
│   │   ├── content
│   │   ├── deployer-combined
│   │   └── discovery
│   └── stage
│       ├── content
│       ├── deployer-combined
│       └── discovery
└── normal
    ├── live
    │   ├── content
    │   ├── deployer-combined
    │   └── discovery
    ├── preview
    │   ├── content
    │   ├── deployer-combined
    │   └── discovery
    └── stage
        ├── content
        ├── deployer-combined
        └── discovery
```

Each group/subgroup has a different port prefix, and all services have the same port suffix. For example:
normal-live-discovery - 8082
normal-live-deployer - 8000
normal-live-content - 8081
express-live-discovery - 9082
express-live-deployer - 9000
express-live-content - 9081
And so on.

```
$ java -jar discovery-registration.jar read
2018-08-09 18:09:53,435 INFO  Main - Registration tool is run with following parameters:
2018-08-09 18:09:53,438 INFO  Main - Configuration file:     cd_storage_conf.xml
2018-08-09 18:09:53,440 INFO  Main - The Command is:         read
2018-08-09 18:09:53,441 INFO  RegistrationTool - Reading configuration from file: 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2018-08-09 18:09:53,725 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating OData client
2018-08-09 18:09:54,932 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Successfully created OData client
2018-08-09 18:09:54,932 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating token provider for OAuth enabled OData client
2018-08-09 18:09:54,933 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Using TokenServiceUrl http://10.1.1.8:8082/token.svc from configuration file.
2018-08-09 18:09:55,071 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Created token provider using TokenServiceUrl from configuration file.
2018-08-09 18:09:55,071 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Successfully created token provider for OAuth enabled OData client
2018-08-09 18:09:55,071 INFO  ReadCommand - Reading all existing Capabilities from discovery-service...
2018-08-09 18:09:55,559 INFO  Main - Result of tool execution is:
[ {
  "Capability" : "com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContentServiceCapability",
  "id" : "DefaultContentService",
  "lastUpdateTime" : 1528313552903,
  "uri" : "http://10.1.1.8:7081/content.svc".        <--- should be 8081
}, {
  "Capability" : "com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.DeployerCapability",
  "id" : "DefaultDeployer",
  "lastUpdateTime" : 1528313553001,
  "strategy" : "DEFAULT",
  "uri" : "http://10.1.1.8:7000/httpupload",         <-- should be 8000
  "extensionProperties" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ {
    "key" : "encoding",
    "value" : "UTF-8"
  }, {
    "key" : "undo.enabled",
    "value" : "false"
  } ] ]
}, {
  "Capability" : "com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.TokenServiceCapability",
  "id" : "DefaultTokenService",
  "lastUpdateTime" : 1528313519092,
  "uri" : "http://10.1.1.8:7082/token.svc".          <--- should be 8082
} ]
```

cd_storage_conf.xml

```
    <Roles>
        <Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://10.1.1.8:8082/token.svc">
        </Role>
        <Role Name="WebCapability">
        </Role>
        <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://10.1.1.8:8000/httpupload">
        </Role>
        <Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="http://10.1.1.8:8081/content.svc">
        </Role>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
```

Comment: For the environment you are explaining, it seems that you are using the same discovery database for all the groups, AFAIK, every discovery set of services, must have its own database.

Comment: Only for curiosity. Why are you setting up the "group" environments? which is the use of the legacy, express and normal groups?

Comment: They use different proprietary extensions and the data ends up in different staging environments. All express subgroups have a higher priority in the queue over the normal subgroup, but they all end up in equivalent staging environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the environment you are explaining, it seems that you are using the same discovery database for all the groups.

AFAIK all the discovery services, are part of a content delivery envireonment, and they need a diferent discovery database. If you are using the same discovery database for more than one delivery environment, when you update and register the microservices of one environment, you are overwriting ythe setup of the previous environment, as all the capabilities has the same name in all the environments.

I'm not sure if it is possible to share the same database, by changing the name of the capabilities for each environment, but i don't thimk so.

Comment: Each group-subgroup of services has their own set of databases, except for normal and express (for internal reasons): they share all their databases, including discovery. This must explain why when I ran the discovery-registration update tool in express, it would update the registration of the express discovery, but when I verified the 'normal' subgroup, all services were registered with the express discovery service.
I'll create a test db for the express group-subgroup (this way each subgroup has their own discovery db), and I'll report back. Thanks!